# JavaScript - Is "yield" a proper identifier name in ES7

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, gecko, ecmascript-2016

I tried to find it out from ES7 specs, but I couldn't find anything precise. Simply, can `yield` be used as a variable name. I mean, is

```
var yield;
```

a syntax error? I made a simple test:

```
var a;
try{eval('var yield')}catch(b){a=1}
console.log(!a);
```

I tried it in Chrome and Node.js (which both use v8 engine) and it prints `true`. But, in Firefox it prints `false`.

As I know, Firefox supports generator function and other ES7 stuff, but it behaves differently. Is it implementation-dependent, or either Chrome or Firefox is wrong?

P.S. I'm asking this because I'm writing a JavaScript obfuscator, so I'm interested if this feature can be exploited.

Comment: Since `yield` is part of the ES2015 standard (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) and is considered a keyword, I would say that it is not appropriate for an identifier.

Comment: Running stuff in the console might produce different results then running the code as an actual script.

Answer (score 4):

`yield` is a reserved word in ES7. But it is allowed in obsolete<sup>1</sup> versions of the language. So the ban on of using `yield` as an identifier is restricted to strict mode.

Hence this generates an error:

```js
"use strict"
var yield = true;
console.log(typeof yield);
```

and this works without breaking the web:

```js
var yield = true;
console.log(typeof yield);
```

These tests behaved the same in current automatically updated versions of Firefox and Chrome, so I am unsure how the differences you detected came about. Firefox 53.0.2 produces a `true` result for the posted code.

---

<sup>1</sup>
More on the history on `yield` as a reserved word.

- ES3 unreserved in either clause 7.5.2 (current) or 7.5.3 (future reserved)
- ES5 introduced as a future reserved word with a requirement to error as an identifier in strict mode (section 7.6.1.2)
- ES6 and ES7 both declare yield as a reserved word in section 11.6.2.1, with a note that usage as an identifer is allowed without error outside of strict mode (section 12.1.1)

Comment: @FelixKling fair enough, I've added "some" more detail :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to the **[ES2015 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords)**:

> **Keywords**
>
> The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may not be used as
>   Identifiers in ECMAScript programs.
>
> Syntax
>
> Keyword :: one of
>
> `break`   `do`    `in`    `typeof` `case` `else`  `instanceof`    `var`
>   `catch`   `export`    `new`   `void` `class`  `extends`   `return`    `while`
>   `const`   `finally`   `super` `with` `continue`   `for`   `switch`    **`yield`**
>   `debugger`    `function`  `this`   `default`  `if`    `throw`  `delete`   `import`    `try`
>
> NOTE: **In some contexts yield is given the semantics of an Identifier. See
>   12.1.1.** In strict mode code, let and static are treated as reserved keywords through static semantic restrictions (see 12.1.1, 13.3.1.1,
>   13.7.5.1, and 14.5.1) rather than the lexical grammar.

Comment: Might be worth quoting 12.1.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code of

```
var yield;
```

results in the error of

> SyntaxError: yield is a reserved identifier

in FireFox

and it is allowed in Chrome, it is implementation dependent, or, if there is any standard for it, it is not followed.